# Force a maximum number of pages in LaTeX

Tags: latex

Is there a way to give LaTeX a hint on the maximum number of pages I would like the document to have, so LaTeX at least tries to not exceed this maximum if possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. LaTeX optimizes text at page level but not document level. So there is no way to automatically squeeze the text into a maximum number of pages. However, there are lots of ways to squeeze things in order to reduce the number of pages. See this blog post on ["Squeezing space with LaTeX"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/squeezing-space-with-latex/).

Comment: The link is good, but putting the content here would be better ;-)

Answer (score 7):

While you can't make a "suggested" page length, you can enforce a page limit where any pages past the limit will not print.  Here's an example of a command you can create in your preamble to do this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcounter{pagecount}
\newcommand{\limitpages}[1]{
    \setcounter{pagecount}{0}%
    \gdef\maxpages{#1}%
    \ifx\latex@outputpage\@undefined\relax%
        \global\let\latex@outputpage\@outputpage%
    \fi%
    \gdef\@outputpage{%
        \addtocounter{pagecount}{1}%
        \ifnum\value{pagecount}>\maxpages\relax%
            % Do not output the page
        \else%
            \latex@outputpage%
        \fi%
    }%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: When would this be useful?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye I've used this before to make preview PDFs for conference papers (page limit 1).  Conceivably you could also use it to do exactly what the original poster wants, but you would need to do a lot of coding to figure out how to adjust the different spacing parameters to give the desired number of pages and then use `\@tempswatrue` to force another round of document generation (there may be other ways to force regen, that's the only one I'm now aware of).

Answer (score -1):

It's good to look at the suggested answer but you should ask yourself why you would like to force LaTeX to restrict the number of pages. With LaTeX you should be focusing on the content and leave most of the formatting for the TeX system. If you're writing too much then learn how to reformulate your words more concisely. Trying to have abnormal settings in LaTeX internal variables may in the end lead to a document that's not aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: That is true but does not answer the question.

Comment: Latex often flows floats in clearly ways.  The same text can end up on on a highly-variable number of output pages, although in the real world LaTeX is used in, documents often have maximum page count requirements.  If there were a hint to LaTeX about how many pages the document can be, it would be another variable in the optimization problem that LaTeX currently solves --- it's far from unreasonable or unrealistic.  Don't criticize the OP.

Comment: @yCalleecaran: in the research world most conferences have a **hard** page limit.